# Hibernate - use MapKeyColumn in OneToMany to get Map of Collections

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I know the basic usage of `@MapKeyColumn` usage, eg:

```
@MapKeyColumn(name = "phone_type", table = "phones")
@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
private Map<PhoneType, Phone> customerPhones;
```

that gets all the customer phones categorized by PhoneType enum.

That works fine if one Customer can have only one Phone of each type.
What I need is to create a mapping that would give me map of collections of phones, eg:

```
@MapKeyColumn(name = "phone_type", table = "phones")
@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
private Map<PhoneType, Collection<Phone>> customerPhones;
```

When I tried above example I've got a:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or
>   @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.myorg.myproject.Customer.customerPhones[java.util.Collection]

Is there any way of doing that?